# GoJS: use more than one parameter in a conversion function

Tags: javascript, gojs

I need to use two properties of a node in GoJS to perform a particular operation. Here is my current code:

```
$(go.Picture,
    {
        //some properties
    },
    new go.Binding("source", "item_status", getIcon)),
//....
function getIcon(item_status) {
    //do something
}
```

Is it possible to modify the above code so that getIcon() function gets a second parameter called item_id? E.g can i do something like this:

```
new go.Binding("source", "item_status","item_id", getIcon)),
....
 function getIcon(item_status, item_id) {}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question again...

to get all data for a particular node, you can pass `""` instead of `"item_status"` to the Binding function.

```
 go.Binding("source", "", getIcon)),
 ...
 getIcon(node){
     var x = node.item_status;
     var y = node.key;
 }
```

Comment: It's awesome. I spent 1 hour to find this in documentation.